# PostgreSQL- sum not recognized as aggregate function?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, cumulative-sum

I need to have running amount of transactions per year. So if total amount at `2015` was `150` and at `2016`, total amount was `90`. It means at `2016` running amount is `240`. And so on.

So I have this data:

```
CREATE table transactions2(year_num int, amount int);

insert into transactions2 values(2015, 100);
insert into transactions2 values(2015, 50);
insert into transactions2 values(2016, 90);
insert into transactions2 values(2017, 100);
insert into transactions2 values(2019, 200);

SELECT year_num, count(amount), sum(amount) 
OVER (ORDER BY year_num) 
FROM transactions2 
GROUP BY year_num ORDER BY year_num;
```

If I run this select SQL, I get:

```
ERROR:  column "transactions2.amount" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 9: SELECT year_num, count(amount), sum(amount) OVER (ORDER BY y...
                                            ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "transactions2.amount" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 328
```

But I have `amount` in `sum` function. So Why it is not working? If I wrap it like `sum(count(sum))`, then it works, but I do not need to have sum of count, I just need sum.

Do I need to write inner select just for this?

Comment: why OVER (ORDER BY year_num)  ?

Comment: @Jack because I need running total of amount as explained in question. It has to add previous year total to next year and so on. With `OVER`, it can be done.

Comment: Ok - I never used OVER for things like this; I would have written it with an inner query

Comment: `sum(sum(amount)) over ...` should work too, but @klin's answer is easier (and already explains why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression:

```
sum(amount) OVER (ORDER BY year_num)
```

`sum()` is not a simple aggregate, it's a window function.

You probably want to use both `count()` and `sum()` as window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year_num, count(amount) over w, sum(amount) over w
FROM transactions2 
WINDOW w as (ORDER BY year_num)
ORDER BY year_num;

 year_num | count | sum 
----------+-------+-----
     2015 |     2 | 150
     2016 |     3 | 240
     2017 |     4 | 340
     2019 |     5 | 540
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Because I've forgotten DISTINCT, sorry. The answer edited.